# How do you backup IIS's metabase in C#?

Tags: iis, directoryservices, metabase

exact code will be helpful. I assume the DirectoryServices namespace does it but I can't find the method that does it.

---

I need actual C# code. All the samples I found so far are VB or VBScript. The C# examples I found are for reading/setting ADSI properties. A command like backup seems to have a certain .NET syntax which I am not clear how to use. In VB there's a straightforward backup command. Need an equivalent in .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost");
 de.Invoke("Backup", new object[0] );

new object needs to be set to hold proper arguments like overwriting current backup

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use ADSI objects. The [IIsComputer.Backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525753.aspx) method is what you want.

As far as how to access ADSI objects from C#, check out this [MSDN page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315716).

**EDIT:** Here's a [sample implementation in C#](http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-470587.html).