# How to restore an IIS Metabase backup using C#

Tags: c#, iis, restore, metabase, iis-metabase

I've found the Stack Overflow question describing how to backup the IIS Metabase in C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089/how-do-you-backup-iiss-metabase-in-c), and I have been successful at getting that to work using the code referenced [here](http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-470587.html). However, I am having difficulty restoring those backups (or indeed any backups created manually in IIS) using C# code.

Does anyone know how to do this, or even if it can be done? I haven't been able to find any examples of this on the web, unlike the backup itself.

I have tried the following code, but receive the error *'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation'*

```
using (DirectoryEntry localhostIIS = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://LocalHost"))
{
   localhostIIS.Invoke("Restore", new object[] { string.Empty, 0, 0});
}
```

Now while I'm sure that I'm calling the method with the wrong name and/or object structure, I haven't been able to find the *correct* way of calling it anywhere....

Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: When you open the InnerException, what HRESULT code do you get?

Comment: I get an E_INVALIDARG 0x80070057.... does that just mean one of the parameters is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with a named backup and got this to work with some tweaks:

```
const uint MD_BACKUP_HIGHEST_VERSION = 0xfffffffe;
const uint MD_BACKUP_NEXT_VERSION = 0xffffffff;
const uint MD_BACKUP_SAVE_FIRST = 2;

using(DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://Localhost"))
{
  // Backup using the next version number (MD_BACKUP_NEXT_VERSION)
  de.Invoke("Backup", new object[] {
      "test-backup",
      MD_BACKUP_NEXT_VERSION,
      MD_BACKUP_SAVE_FIRST
  });

  // Restore the highest version number (or specify the specific version)
  de.Invoke("Restore", new object[] {
    "test-backup",
    MD_BACKUP_HIGHEST_VERSION,
    0
  });
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much - looks like I only needed the MD_BACKUP_HIGHEST_VERSION constant :o)